# Can I hide 1 column only in the dispform of a list for users which are not in the administrators group?

Tags: display-form

I have a Sharepoint 2013 portal. I have a list with 10 columns in the content type. 1 of the 10 columns I would like to hide or set readonly if the user is not in the administrator group. Is this possible? If there is a Gui solution please let me know, otherwise other programmaticaly or js also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/
I´ve tested it on SharePoint Foundation 2010, not on SharePoint 2013